# Python K-Means clustering and maximum distance

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

I would like to start by saying that my knowledge of clustering techniques is extremely limited, please don’t shoot me down too harshly.

I have a sizable set of 3D points (around 8,000) - think of a X, Y, Z triplets, for which the Z coordinate represents a point in the earth underground (negative). I would like to cluster these points using the absolute minimum number of clusters, with the following constraints:

1. Use the least number of clusters
2. All points should be included in the clustering, which means that any point should at least belong to one cluster
3. The maximum distance between any point and the cluster centroid (shifted at Z=0, on the earth surface) should not exceed a certain fixed distance *d*.

I was thinking to use scikit-learn k-means approach, by iteratively incrementing the number of clusters and then, for all points in the dataset calculate if the distance between the point and the cluster centroid (at Z=0) is less than the specific distance provided.

Of course, I am open to better/more efficient suggestions - the clusters, for example, do not need to be circular as the ones returned by k-means. They can be ellipses or anything else, as long as the constraints above are satisfied.

I welcome any suggestion, thank you for your insights.

Comment: Have you looked at the [MeanShift](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.MeanShift.html#sklearn-cluster-meanshift) algorithm?

Answer (score -1):

Use hierarchical clustering.

With complete linkage.

Finding the true minimum cover is NP hard. So you don't want to do this. But this should produce a fairly good approximation in "just" O(n³).

This is basic knowledge. When looking for a clustering algorithm, at least read the Wikipedia article. Better even some book, to get an overview. There is not just k-means...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and for the downvote. Reading around StackOverflow it’s kind of sad to notice that one really has to be careful about what to ask regarding clustering - or incur in your downvote. However, this is irrelevant; I thought hierarchical clustering with complete linkage was working - but it doesn’t: the maximum distance “constraint” is a distance between any two points in the cluster - not between the centroid and any point in it. I could double the distance, but then I can guarantee that there will be points that are further away from the centroid than the distance I want.

Comment: Well there are so many more variants of is not yet quite what you wanted. You could also define your own, you know... But there is LEADER, for example, centroid linkage, and MiniMax linkage. Just read a little bit (including earlier questions, hence the downvote for lack of research). https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/303553/is-there-a-clustering-algorithm-that-can-take-a-maximum-distance-from-any-mean-a